# Make all controls inside a GroupBox read-only?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, groupbox

I know that many individual controls have a `ReadOnly` property. But suppose I have a `GroupBox` in which there are many different controls (text boxes, combo boxes, radio buttons, etc ..), is it possible to set the `ReadOnly` property for all these controls together?

Not that I only want to set this property for the controls within a specific `GroupBox` (because I have multiple GroupBoxes too, so I don't want the setting to be done for controls in other GroupBoxes) ..

Manually setting the `ReadOnly` property seems very lethargic, as I have as many as 20 controls in each `Groupbox` (don't ask why :p).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For standart controls in Winform you can use something like this ([TextBoxBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.aspx) is base class for [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx) properties controls) :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetReadonlyControls(groupBox1.Controls);
    }

    private void SetReadonlyControls(Control.ControlCollection controlCollection)
    {
        if (controlCollection == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (TextBoxBase c in controlCollection.OfType<TextBoxBase>())
        {
            c.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If disabled is enough you can disable the group box and the children will be disabled, too.

If you want to set inputs to read-only you need to iterate over the children, find out using reflection if they have an `IsReadOnly` property and then set it.

Comment: Disabled is not the solution because that darkens the controls too much. I really need the `ReadOnly` option :(

Comment: Instead of reflection, you can use the `is` operator to test the type of the control object and then cast if appropriately. This should work fine, since you know what controls you're likely to have in the GroupBox and you know whether or not that type of control has a `ReadOnly` property. The `is` operator will be significantly faster than reflection, and although premature optimization is evil and all that, there seems to be no legitimate reason to prefer reflection here when a simpler solution exists.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree if there are just a few well-known control types. This didn't even occur to me.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, `as` is an even better choice as it avoids a redundant check of the object's type. But yeah, there are only a handful of controls in WinForms that even implement the `ReadOnly` property, so this should be easy to do. If I remember correctly, it may only be text boxes! The rest will need to be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Using Daniil's answer, since you mentioned there exists ComboBoxes and RadioButtons as well.  This code :

```
TextBoxBase c in controlCollection.OfType<TextBoxBase>()
```

wont be able to catch RadioButtons and ComboBoxes. You need to add following foreach loops as well.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetReadonlyControls(groupBox1.Controls);
    }

    private void SetReadonlyControls(Control.ControlCollection controlCollection)
    {
        if (controlCollection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (RadioButton r in controlCollection.OfType<RadioButton>())
        {
            r.Enabled = false; //RadioButtons do not have readonly property
        }
        foreach (ComboBox c in controlCollection.OfType<ComboBox>())
        {
            c.Enabled = false;//ComboBoxes do not have readonly property
        }
        foreach (TextBoxBase c in controlCollection.OfType<TextBoxBase>())
        {
            c.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

EDIT :

Make sure all the controls are inside groupbox1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void SetReadonlyControls(Control.ControlCollection controlCollection)
        {
            if (controlCollection == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach (RadioButton r in controlCollection.OfType<RadioButton>())
            {
                r.Enabled = false; //RadioButtons do not have readonly property
            }
            foreach (ComboBox c in controlCollection.OfType<ComboBox>())
            {//AQUE
                var text = new TextBox();
                controlCollection.Add(text);
                text.Text = c.Text;
                text.Location = c.Location;
                text.Size = c.Size;
                text.Visible = true;`enter code here`
                c.Visible = false;
               /* c.Enabled = false;//ComboBoxes do not have readonly property
                c.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
               c.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.Simple;*/
            }
            foreach (TextBoxBase c in controlCollection.OfType<TextBoxBase>())
            {
                c.ReadOnly = true;
            }
            foreach (DateTimePicker c in controlCollection.OfType<DateTimePicker>())
            {
                c.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.