# Making UserControls and sub controls read only in WPF

Tags: wpf-controls

I have a user control with several user controls in it. I now need to make some of the controls read only. What would be the best way to do this?

I came across this: [Make all controls inside a GroupBox read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597271/make-all-controls-inside-a-groupbox-read-only). Would this be the best way to do it?

I have used Dependency Properties to achieve what I want, but it is a real schlep and maintaining that code won't be fun.

I also tried looking at using the Visual and Logical tree, but that seems to be an overly complicated solution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up binding each control's read only property (the ones that have) within the user control to a "read only" dependency property I created on the user control. then I simply set the bool value in xaml.

I can provide an example upon request.