# Disable few controls on window form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm working on C# Project with windows forms. few controls that I'm mostly using are : group box, button, label, text box etc.

I'm using a function that used to disable all controls once as i pass a Boolean value to this function. But this function does not help every time , because in mostly cases I don't need this, rather than that I've to disable only few controls in mostly cases.

Is there a way to disable some controls on form except for a all controls?
In the current situation, I want to disable all controls inside a group box only.

I google it for solution. There are different solutions where someone can disable all controls using some loop for example foreach loop.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @kyle yes. I was working on a School Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable any container and all the controls within that will automatically be disabled. I'm not sure about the group-box but Panel control does that.

Answer (score 0):

If disabled is enough you can disable the group box and the children will be disabled, too.

OR
you can do it by:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetReadonlyControls(groupBox1.Controls);
}

private void SetReadonlyControls(Control.ControlCollection controlCollection)
{
    if (controlCollection == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (TextBoxBase c in controlCollection.OfType<TextBoxBase>())
    {
        c.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

[The Code is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599189/1509986)